# timer still in the queue despite flush in fakeAsync

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have this test that will result in the infamous "1 timer(s) still in the queue" error:

```js
import {
discardPeriodicTasks,
  fakeAsync,
  flush,
  flushMicrotasks,
  tick
} from "@angular/core/testing";

describe("Sleep", () => {
  const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  it("should sleep async", async () => {
    let slept = false;
    await sleep(0).then(() => (slept = true));
    expect(slept).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should sleep fakeAsync", fakeAsync(async () => {
    let slept = false;
    await sleep(0).then(() => (slept = true));
    flush();
    flushMicrotasks();
    discardPeriodicTasks();
    tick(1000);
    expect(slept).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

No amount of flushing or ticking including the hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900623/2080575) will get rid of the timer. What else can I do? The variant without `fakeAsync()` works fine.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-jasmine-karma-fakeasync-timer?file=app/test.ts

Comment: Does it help when you call `flush()` _after_ `tick()`?

Comment: Nope, adding a second flush doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, it works if you convert the `sleep(0)` `Promise` into an `Observable` instead.

```js
it("should sleep fakeAsync", fakeAsync(async () => {
  let slept = false;
  //await sleep(0).then(() => (slept = true));
  from(sleep(0)).subscribe(() => (slept = true));
  expect(slept).toBeFalsy();
  tick(0);
  expect(slept).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

I ran into a similar problem with `debounceTime` from Rxjs where no amount of `flush()`, `flushMicroTasks()` or `discardPeriodicTasks()` would release the debounce.    However in my case I was able to resolve my problem by making a call to `tick()` with a sufficiently large time value after my expectation had finished to allow the `debounceTime` to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; it does solve the problem for the fake example I provided. Unfortunately, it does not solve my real problem of a native `async` buried somewhere in a library when replacing `Promise.all().then()` with `forkJoin().subscribe()`. It's still nicer with Observables, though

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem in stackblitz removing the `await` in `fakeAsync`, because the point of fakeAsync is run synchronously.

So, the modified working test is:

```js
it("should sleep fakeAsync", fakeAsync(() => {
    let slept = false;
    sleep(100).then(() => (slept = true));
    flush();
    expect(slept).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

You just need to use `flush` to process your timeout time synchronously and the test will pass as expected. Another answer to support my point about `fakeAsync` and `async`: [Angular testing: using fakeAsync with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739584/angular-testing-using-fakeasync-with-async-await).

I was still getting this error in my test for nested timeout, a timeout inside a service that is inside a request subscribe. This solution doesn't solve my problem. So I dropped the `fakeAsync` approach and use the one suggested here: [Test a function that contains a setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772989/test-a-function-that-contains-a-settimeout) and finally I solved my problem.